# chttp2_transport.cc:748 exception server stream 17 still included in list 0

Tags: grpc

I met a exception when I use grpc v1.8.x version and also v.1.7.x version:

`E0111 07:32:20.953644757    2249 chttp2_transport.cc:748]    server stream 17 still included in list 0
*** Aborted at 1515655940 (unix time) try "date -d @1515655940" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGABRT (@0x6e3) received by PID 1763 (TID 0x7fdf13fff700) from PID 1763; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fe10a56f390 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe10a1c9428 gsignal
    @     0x7fe10a1cb02a abort
    @     0x7fe0d92ea1c6 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe0d92df4cc grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx
    @     0x7fe0d92b58a2 grpc_exec_ctx_flush
    @     0x7fe0d92b5fac (unknown)
    @     0x7fe0d92b60f5 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe0d92dc557 (unknown)
    @     0x7fe10a5656ba start_thread
    @     0x7fe10a29b3dd clone
    @                0x0 (unknown)`

This failure doesn't happen often, a few hours or a few minutes.
Can some give some advice about it? My server is [grpc_server.h](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/blob/develop/paddle/operators/detail/grpc_server.h)  [grpc_server.cc](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/blob/develop/paddle/operators/detail/grpc_server.cc) which is a async server with two type calls. And it's proto is [here](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/blob/develop/paddle/operators/detail/send_recv.proto)

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look. Could you try locking around `AsyncGRPCServer::ShutDown()` instead of `AsyncGRPCServer::ShutdownQueue()`?

If that doesn't work is there any way you could try to turn this into a reproducible unit test? It's very hard to track these things down otherwise. I don't see anything glaring in your code